# deleting messages if a certain username said it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
discordClient.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {

    async function dt() {

        if (message.content.includes('has been timed out for')){

            const user = message.content.split(" ")[1]
            const time = message.content.split(" ")[7]

            if (message.content === `** ${user} has been timed out for ${time} seconds.**`) {
                
                await message.channel.messages.fetch({
                    limit: 20 
                }).then((messages) => {
                    const msg = [];
                    messages.filter(m => m.author.username.toLowerCase() === user.toLowerCase()).forEach(message => msg.push(message))
                    message.channel.bulkDelete(msg).then(() => {
                        console.log('cleared messages')
                    });
                })
            }
    
          
        }
    }

    dt().catch(error)

    });
```

I made something that makes Twitch chat logs display on Discord, but I am now trying to make it that if a user has been timed out it deletes their messages. The code works fine but if someone typed it in chat it will consider it the same as a timeout so people in chat can delete messages on Discord. Is there any possible way to make it if a certain username did this then you apply the code using webhooks?

[image]

The one with the name `User Timed Out` I got it from `/timeout` on Twitch but with `DancingPotato` I just typed the same words as what it would do if it deleted the message without **/timeout** and it will clear the messages of both.

Comment: Isn't it just that you need to get index `0`? Can you try that? `const user = message.content.split(" ")[1]` > `const user = message.content.split(" ")[0]`

You can also split the message once and after that put them in an array

Comment: no that is not the problem i am getting the username 0 will give me ** 1 gives me the name but I want it if the username like User Timed Out said it it deletes the messages this is the line it tries to take it from `'** ${username} has been timed out for ${duration['ban-duration']} seconds.**' `